# Download video like whatsApp does in chat screen

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, whatsapp

I am developing chat application. Currently i have implemented all functionality in chat screen. For sending image , video and text. I can able to download image.

Now i want to download videos like whatsapp does. For eg, when click on download video and navigate to other screen and back to chat screen that video downloading.

My question is that what functionality whatsApp uses for downloading videos?

I can able to download video simply using **BroadcastReceiver**. But i need same functionality same as whatsApp.

Advanced help would be appreciated !

Comment: Please clarify the question explaining how Whatsapp does it.

Comment: Like, in whatsApp chat screen when receiver side we download the video progress bar shows with cross icon. Now when we navigate to other screen and back to chat screen that progress bar is showing and downloading the video.!

Comment: `which libraries I can use`  only Whatsapp developers know that. We are not Whatsapp developers. `functionality same as whatsApp` don't expect that everybody here uses whatsapp. Instead describe in words what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can write separate `DownloadManager` class. It should be singleton.

All the work related to downloading any file will be done by this Manager. It will also hold state of the downloading file.

So next time user come into that chat screen, You will need to ask `DownloadManager` about state of that and it will return that.

Comment: I don't want use download manager. Because it will be easy for me and there is no issue in that.Download manager don't give that functionality. Thanks !

Comment: Dude, I'm not talking about DownloadManager of Android. Write your own simple class which deals with it.

Comment: You need something that holds Downloading state with progress. If you write some separate singleton which does this, you can achieve the thing you wants! 

Whenever you get onto chat screen, You need to query download manager about state.

If that is not working, then you need to make it working.

Thanks!

Comment: "I have already done that ! But it is not working properly" then fix the issues you're having.